# Ruby on Rails + Passenger, ENV not changing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

First of all, our project structure is a bit different than a regular ruby on rails project therefore we don't have anything like environment.rb.

I am running into an issue changing the ENV variables. The server keeps starting under development mode.

```
Environment (value of RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, WSGI_ENV, NODE_ENV and PASSENGER_APP_ENV)
development
```

I tried changing those variables like this `export RAILS_ENV=production` and restarting the server using `service httpd restart` but for some reason none of these variables will change.

My question is, where can I possibly find/override those variables in a file?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the environment variables in the `/etc/environment` file on your server.  I had a similar issue recently and that seemed to resolve it for me.  It would look something like FOO=bar

Answer (score 1):

Found it. It was under my `httpd.conf` where I just changed variable `RailsEnv` to production

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 5, these lines are moved from .htaccess to apache configuration file.

```
RackBaseURI /
PassengerAppRoot /path/to/public_html
RailsEnv production
```

I am running on apache 2.4.18, Phusion Passenger 5.2.1.